# Wrapfig - why is figure placed in margins?

Tags: wrapfigure

I've created a wrapfig environment

```
\newenvironment{usefulterms}{
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}[0pt]{0.05\textwidth}
\vspace{-15pt}
\includegraphics[width = 0.05\textwidth]{abc.jpg}
\vspace{-25pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent{\textbf{Useful Terms}} \\
\newline}
{\newline}
```

The problem is that even thought I specify an overhang of 0pt, it is still placed in the margin;

[image]

Why is this command being "disobeyed"?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Can you provide an MWE (minimal working example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that material inside an environment is placed inside a group, which confuses `wrapfig`. Page 1 of the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig), says

> If you put a wrapfigure in a parbox or a minipage, or any other type
>   of grouping, the text wrapping should end before the group does.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the work-around would be to specify this kind of thing as a command, and not an environment.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late on this, but note that it is possible to create an environment which contains a working `wrapfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{environ}% to collect the body of the environment
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \AfterEndEnvironment hook
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show that they don't go into the margin

\AfterEndEnvironment{afterend}{\AfterEnd}

\newcommand{\setafterend}[1]{%
  \gdef\AfterEnd{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}[0pt]{2cm}%
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%
    #1%
  }%
}
\NewEnviron{afterend}%
{%
  \expandafter\setafterend\expandafter{\BODY}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{afterend}
  foo
\end{afterend}
\begin{afterend}
  bar
\end{afterend}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And chiming in even later. The facility to define new environments is there in wrapfig.sty (see below) but in this example with a tiny image (icon) surely the wrapping would be finished before the environment closes. I think all it needs is a proper `\par` at the end instead of `\newline`. I also took the liberty of adjusting vertical spacing

```
\newenvironment{usefulterms}{\par
 \bigskip
 \begin{wrapfigure}{l}[0pt]{0.05\textwidth}
 \vspace{-15pt}
 \includegraphics[width = 0.05\textwidth]{icon-image}
 \vspace{-25pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent{\textbf{Useful Terms}}\\*[7pt]}
{\par\bigskip}
```

I wasn't sure about the purpose of the negative `\vspace`s, so I left them, but I expect they are partially meant to counteract `\intextsep`, which could be set to zero in the environment.

About making new environments, even the wrapfig environment is defined in terms of `\wrapfloat` and `\endwrapfloat` which are meant to be used in new environment definitions. That's not a magic fix because the figure and the wrapping will try to start after the end of the new environment, not within it. So the fix is to launch the placement within the new environment.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sillytimes}{\par
  \mbox{}\par
  \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
  \wrapfloat{figure}{l}[0pt]{5pt}
   \rule{5pt}{45pt}% Instead of an image, use a rule
  \endwrapfloat
  \WF@startfloating % Perform placement here
 \noindent\textbf{Silly Times}\\*[7pt]}
{\par\mbox{}\par\aftergroup\par}
```

In this definition, `\WF@startfloating` initiates placement at the following `\noindent`. Instead of an image, there is a tall thick rule. I changed the `\bigskip` to `\mbox{}\par` so line-counting more closely matches vertical position. The `\aftergroup\par` helps ensure the wrapping ends or continues appropriately in the text following the environment.